# Plot 2 graphs simultaneously using different colors and label them in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm studying R and made a simple data to draw a scatter plot.
Here is the simple code that I made:

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(date = c(20120324,20120329,20121216,20130216,20130725,20130729,20130930,20131015,20131124,20131225),
                 math=c(54,32,45,78,89,12,33,46,79,100),
                 physics=c(100,100,23,24,55,66,34,37,89,39))
df$date<-ymd(df$date)

math<-df$math
physics<-df$physics
date<-df$date
plot(date,math,xlab="year",ylab="math")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(date,physics,xlab="year",ylab="physics")
```

What I was trying to do was to draw the scatter plots simultaneously in one plane and give them labels to differentiate each other. So my goal is to plot `math` and `physics` using different colors. I think red and blue will be fine. I want to make x axis to represent the year. In `date` column, `20120324` means March 24th, 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions in `tidyverse` package to pivot your data into the longer format, and then plot using ggplot.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, colour=name)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(breaks="year", 
               date_labels="%Y", 
               limits=as.Date(c("2012-01-01","2014-01-01")))
```

[image]